# How to reduce the execution time of query since planning time is less than execution time?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT  "conversations".*
FROM "conversations"
   INNER JOIN "messages"
      ON "messages"."conversation_identifier" = "conversations"."conversation_identifier"
WHERE "conversations"."project_id" = 2
  AND (person_messages_count > 0 and deleted IS NULL)
  AND (conversations.status = 'closed')
  AND ((messages.tsv_message_content)
      @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'help' || ' ''' || ':*')))
ORDER BY conversations.updated_at DESC LIMIT 30;
```

```
                                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=6895.78..6895.85 rows=30 width=398) (actual time=197364.691..197364.730 rows=30 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=6895.78..6895.86 rows=34 width=398) (actual time=197364.688..197364.702 rows=30 loops=1)
         Sort Key: conversations.updated_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..6894.91 rows=34 width=398) (actual time=9.625..197314.491 rows=24971 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using indexing_by_conversations_status on conversations  (cost=0.56..704.27 rows=64 width=398) (actual time=2.832..14181.496 rows=25362 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((project_id = 2) AND (person_messages_count > 0) AND (deleted IS NULL) AND ((status)::text = 'closed'::text))
               ->  Index Scan using index_messages_on_conversation_identifier on messages  (cost=0.56..96.63 rows=10 width=46) (actual time=3.709..7.217 rows=1 loops=25362)
                     Index Cond: ((conversation_identifier)::text = (conversations.conversation_identifier)::text)
                     Filter: (tsv_message_content @@ '''help'':*'::tsquery)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 15
 Planning time: 46.814 ms
 Execution time: 197366.064 ms
```

Planning time seems to be lower the actual execution time. Is there any way to reduce the execution time?

Comment: The fact that planning time is lower than execution time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. The estimates on `conversations` are woefully wrong:

   ```
   ANALYZE conversations;
   ```
2. You should index the selective full text search condition:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON messages USING gin (tsv_message_content);
   ```

If `ANALYZE` (even with raised `default_statistics_target`) doesn't improve the mis-estimate, it is probably caused by correlation between the columns.
Try extended statistics to improve that:

```
CREATE STATISTICS conversations_stats (dependencies)
   ON project_id, deleted, status FROM conversations;
```

A subsequent `ANALYZE` should improve the estimate.

Comment: I have this index `CREATE INDEX ON messages USING gin (tsv_message_content);` But the query planner didn't choose this index :(

Comment: Then you have to solve the remaining and primary problem, the mis-estimate (34 instead of 24971 rows).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve that mis-estimate? I tried vacuum, analyse and also tried with various index.

Comment: I have extended the answer with an idea.